# How to change the screen before the splash screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-splashscreen

The foreground of my mipmap logo shows along with a grey background before my custom made splash screen shows over my webview (the splash screen gets shown from `onCreate()`):

[image]

I want to change the background color to white, and also, if possible, change the image to instead of the foreground of the app icon, show both the background and foreground so it shows as a complete logo. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Here's some of my code:

`AndroidManifest`:

```
<application
    ....
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_favicon_1144_round"
    ....
```

`ic_favicon_1144_round`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <background android:drawable="@color/ic_favicon_1144_background"/>
     <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo_48_foreground"/>
 </adaptive-icon>
```

By the way, I haven't done any code to show the foreground or the grey background specifically. If you'd like to see any more code just drop a comment and I'll edit in my question. Any help on this would be really appriecated, even if you can't awnser the entire question! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the latest splash screen if you are using android 12 and above

you should ad this code in your `theme.xml`

```
</style>

<style name="Theme.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/purple_700</item>
<item 
 name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_round_local_movies_24</item>
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MoviesApp</item>
</style>
```

you can adjust the icon and background in here

and of course you should add this code to your `manifest` file in the `activity section`

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Starting"
```

and this code in you main activity, after onCreate and before setContent view

```
val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Farshad Moazeinali! I've just tried that and it mostly works. There's a few modifications I need to make but apart from that, it seems to work ok :)